# Attempt to link objects makes them recompile even if up-to-date

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a recipe in my makefile that relies on several object files. I would like it to simply link the them, but they are always recompiling.
I've googled around and found information I did not know(marked with #) and changed it a bit, but the problem persisted.

I am led to believe make expects the name of the recipe be the name of the file, and I am failing to accomplish that. The problem is I do not what else to try and fix this. I would appreciate any help

```
CC = g++
#.PHONY: sfml-app

LIBS = -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

APPLICATION = sfml-app

INCLUDE_DIR = -I include/
SOURCE_DIR  = source
OUTPUT_DIR  = bin

SOURCES     = $(wildcard $(SOURCE_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS     = $(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES)))

#$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(APPLICATION): $(OBJECTS)
#bin/sfml-app: $(OBJECTS)
#sfml-app: $(OBJECTS)
#$(APPLICATION): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/*.o $(LIBS) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(APPLICATION)

%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLUDE_DIR) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$@

clean:
    rm $(OUTPUT_DIR)/*

print-%  : ; @echo $* = $($*)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule doesn't create the file it promises to:

> ```
> %.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp
>     $(CC) -c $< $(INCLUDE_DIR) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$@
> ```

See that `-o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$@`?  That's instructing the compiler to create a file in `$(OUTPUT_DIR)` instead of in the working directory.

If you really want your object files to go in `$(OUTPUT_DIR)`, you need to make sure that your rule indicates that:

```
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLUDE_DIR) -o $@
```

Or better, to act like the standard `%.o: %.c` rule (which will include `CFLAGS` etc):

```
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o: $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

I note your input files are named `*.cpp` - usually, that convention is for C++ files (i.e. to be compiled with `$(COMPILE.cc)`, which will invoke `$(CXX)` rather than `$(CC)`).  Check that you've not mixed up your C and C++ sources!

Comment: Oh, I did not think the problem would be with the object recipe. I am indeed promising a file I do not supply. Is `.PHONY: $(OBJECTS)` a bad solution?

Comment: Your suggestion completely solves the issue. It was me not seeing where the problem came from: I changed the OBJECTS to `OBJECTS     = $(addprefix $(OUTPUT_DIR)/, $(notdir $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCES))))`

Comment: You can do that with a single `patsubst`, I think: `OBJECTS = $(patsubst, $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))`.  Definitely wrong to write `.PHONY: $(OBJECTS)` - that has exactly the opposite effect, and will result in them always being made even when up to date.  OTOH, you *do* want `.PHONY: clean` so that the `clean` actions will be run even if you have a file called `clean`.